# Strange text overflowing page

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have noticed that when i visit my website some wierd text overflows the content in some pages, not all of them.
When i use the Computer everyting is fine, just when i use a phone.
The message says:

```
demo.gudeg.co
[] Safe Website
[] 0 Trackers
[]
[]
[] Feedback
Safe link
This website is safe to use.
Go to website Back
Safe website

This website is safe to use.

Take me away!
Add exception Exception added []
expection Exception removed
[]
```

Here also a screenshot of the problem: [image: Problem]

What is this and how can i remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap a  around your content and define a width/min-width - It's clear you're using absolute/relative positioning for everything so it is causing it to overlap.

Otherwise I recommend learning about CSS media queries for CSS3. These allow you to change the website depending on the screen used for viewing it. Your website was designed for your sized monitor and will have adverse affects if you use other sized monitors you will also see a difference.

Could you please post some code if you still need assistance.

Comment: Thanks you. :)
The @media screen and (max-width: 300px) was wrong. :D